# Best approach for surface matching (halcon)?

Tags: computer-vision, halcon

My aim is finding the surface of a 3D model into a point cloud acquired with laser triangulation. I'm doing some trys in Halcon with different approaches but im a bit confused about.
Can anyone share his experience in something similar  with halcon?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and improve your post. also mind your wording. you cannot "find a surface into a point cloud". also "Can anyone share his experience?" is not the kind of question you are supposed to ask here...

Answer (score 3):

May be a bit late, but if you look in the folder `%HALCONEXAMPLES%`, there should be some examples to get you started with surface matching. If you are using `HDevelop`, you can quite easily start the examples located in the following folder:

`%HALCONEXAMPLES%\hdevelop\3D-Matching\Surface-Based`